# Is it possible to apply a different aggregation projection to each document in the aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Consider this collection:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    nest: [
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-19T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nest: [
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to generate an aggregation that has the same shape as the original collection but limits the number of `objects` in `nest` depending on the particular document. For instance, for the first member of the collection, I want objects with `date` less than or equal to `"2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"`, and for the second member, I want objects with `date` less than or equal to `"2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"`. So this would be my desired output:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    nest: [
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-19T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nest: [
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z'
      },
      object: {
        date: '2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The furthest I've gotten will apply a static date to all members of the collection, like this:

```
{
  $project: {
    nest: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$nest",
        as: "nested",
        cond: { $lte: [ "$$nested.date", <date-goes-here> ] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would apply whatever date I use to all members of the collection, which is not what I want.

How can I achieve my desired output? Thanks!

**Update**

This is for an endpoint that returns chats for either 1:1 or group chats. Each member of the collection is a chat, and the `nest` object is the array of messages in a particular chat. I want to paginate the number of messages returned when the client requests group chats, so my idea is to fetch only the messages that came before the date specified by the client. The client could send a request saying that for chat 1 (which is a group chat), it wants messages sent on or before `"2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"`, and that for chat 2 (also a group chat), it wants messages sent on or before `"2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"`. I use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to get the chats requested by the client, and I want to use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to filter out the messages that come after the date specified by the client for that chat.

Comment: How about if you've more documents in collection ? What condition should be applied from 3 & more ?

Comment: It depends on each member of the collection. I tried to simplify the scenario but basically for documents with some properties I apply this filter and for others I don’t. I did that using `$cond`. But the catch is that for every document that requires the filter, it will require its own unique date.

Comment: Is the date for the condition present in the document, or can it be derived from something in the document? You might want to include logic how to compute the date.

Comment: @TheeSritabtim i've added some more detail, let me know if you need any more. Thanks!

Comment: In the `$filter`'s `cond`, you can specify condition as: `(id = 1 AND nested.date lte "2020-04-20") OR (id = 2 AND nested.date lte "2020-04-24")`.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena Can the client request more than 2 chats simultaneously? If so, what is the maximum?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim yes it can be more than 2, max is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible but to do that you must create an JSON Object basically key value pair based on the user input like

```
datesHash = { chatId:date,chatId2:date2} // these id's and dates will be based on user input as you mentioned above.
```

then just use that smartly in above aggregation like

```
{
  $project: {
    nest: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$nest",
        as: "nested",
        cond: { $lte: [ "$$nested.date", datesHash["$_id"] ] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried recreating your solution on working sample https://play.db-ai.co/m/Xr3LWwbYvgABFVSC ( this is just for reference not the exact solution )

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I haven't been able to get it to work. Can you confirm if it works for you if you use `datesHash["$_id"]` instead of the `datesHash["$id"]`? `_id` is the Object ID and that's what I'm actually using, and so far it's not working (I'm getting back an empty result, as in nothing is getting projected at all).

Comment: oh that was typo i'll edit that and yes if you use $_id it should work well as i've tried this approach in multiple projects